# How to access the id attribute present under last aside section

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML as shown below

```
 <div style="" class="Topping-details" id="4">
   <section id="topping_tsection_4">
      <aside>
         <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>
         <section class="secclass">
            <a data-id="4" topping_id="1" id="4_KK_0_KK_0" topp_name="Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 
               ML" top_price="25" class="" qt_val="4_KK_0_KK_0">
               Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 
               ML 
               <p class="tcPriceWrap">25</p>
            </a>
         </section>
      </aside>
      <aside>
         <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      2</h6>
         <section class="secclass">
            <a data-id="4" topping_id="1" id="4_KK_1_KK_0" topp_name="Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML" top_price="25" class="tpActive" qt_val="4_KK_1_KK_0">
               Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 
               ML 
               <p class="tcPriceWrap">25</p>
            </a>
         </section>
      </aside>
   </section>
</div>
```

I am trying to access the last id present under class secclass

I have tried this way

```
var id_attr_val = 4;
 var valueee =$(".Topping-details").find('section#topping_tsection_'+id_attr_val+' aside:last')attr('id');
```

I am expecting a output of **4_KK_1_KK_0**.
But its giving me undefined .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aside` element does not have an id, the `id` belong to the `a` element inside the `aside`

```
var id_attr_val = 4;
var valueee = $('#topping_tsection_' + id_attr_val + ' aside:last a').attr('id');
```

Also note since you have the `id` of the `section` there is no need to use the class selector `Topping-details`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7u7hxtgz/)